# React-native app crashes on IOS using version:0.20.0

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native version:0.20.0, my app crashes on IOS and shows an error  in Xcode. Below I have attached the error message.
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I can fix this or why this may be happening?

Comment: Is it an app you just created with `react-native init` ?

Comment: no after running the app

Comment: Hmmm, without any code, I can't do much I'm afraid.

Comment: kk, but error is in RCTwebSocket.m file